# asp:Gridview annoyance How to display grid

Tags: gridview

I'm laying out template web pages for a rather large web site and many pages will be using the GridView control.  I will, of course, EVENTUALLY be binding the grid to a data source.  But for right now, as I lay out the template pages, I just want an empty grid to display -- I just need to see the column headers and an empty row.

Sadly, this control seems to want to remain completely invisible unless it's actually bound to a datasource.  Again, this is going to happen eventually,.  But right now, I'm trying to lay out a large number of pages for end-user approval an I just need the frickin' empty grid to show up on the page where it should be.  In fact, the database from which we'll be pulling data is under development and subject to change, so binding to data right now is IMHO a waste of time.  I just want to template a bunch of pages!

All of the StackOverflow hits I get when searching this topic deal with grids already bound to a data source -- no help to me in this situation.  I'm trying something like below.  Is what I'm attempting even possible with this control?

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdReportList" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"   
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">  
        <Columns>  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True"   
                SortExpression="Name" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"   
                SortExpression="Description" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type"   
                SortExpression="Type" />  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Inactive" HeaderText="Inactive"   
                SortExpression="Inactive" />  
        </Columns>  
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help: [GridView.EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx)

EDIT:  Just noticed that these GridView control properties were not set

```
ShowHeader=True (this is default)
ShowFooter=True (set if you want footer)
ShowHeaderWhenEmpty=True  ( Ahaaaaa!)
```

EDIT: unbound, header only Gridview Example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Header A" HeaderText="Header A" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Header A"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Header B" HeaderText="Header B" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Header B" DataFormatString="{0:F2}"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Header C" HeaderText="Header C" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Header C"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Header D" HeaderText="Header D" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Header D" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="Select null as [Header A], 1234 as [Header B],'C' as [Header C], cast('1/1/2014' as datetime) as [Header D]" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMSConnectionString %>'>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Gridview requires a datasource, even if that datasource points to nothing. The above has a connection string to a valid database, but it pulls data strictly from the select statement (note the lack of a `FROM` clause), which provides both the header text and a row of fake data.

As you can see, I'm returning a few type of values and formatted in the bound field controls.  BUT, be aware, if you refresh the grid, and AutoGenerateColumns is enabled, you will lose all formatting as the gridview will replace the fields. So once you have the grid populated with the header and data as you like, **disable the AutoGenerateColumns** option in the gridview context menu before formatting.

Modify as necessary to populate the grid. Wash, rinse, repeat for all grids.

This could just as easily have been a local Datasource in your App_Data directory. Which is likely what you'd need for the rapid prototyping your trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That's a nice stopgap solution.  It lets me show SOMETHING, but an image or text isn't going to help here.  I need to show an empty grid with all the proper column headers in place.  These are templates for end-user approval, and they are going to want to see grids there on the web page.  I've worked with the corresponding control in WinForms apps before and it definitely does NOT behave this way, so I'm very confused by this behavior.  Why stay INVISIBLE just because there's no data?

Comment: Maybe as a bandwidth optimization? I'm assuming that you have the ShowHeader, ShowFooter, and ShowHeaderWhenEmpty control properties set to true?

Comment: fnostro, your Aha! moment seemed like the sure answer, but no joy :-(  I did NOT originally have ShowHeaderWhenEmpty set to true, so I did that, and was positive it would work.  But no.  Also added the other two to be safe (never know when Microsoft might decide to change the value of a default).  I think I'm going to have to abandon the GridView in favor of some other grid control.  I hate to do this, but given the # of pages I'm having to template for this project, I really need to show empty grids with proper column names right now, and that is all.  Binding data is not an option yet

Comment: live data trumps mock-up any day :) if the data is easily available no reason to not use it. cheers.

Comment: No disagreement fnostro :-)  Data wasn't easily available though -- the database wasn't ready as we began doing our templating but we knew what the grids were supposed to contain, so having an empty grid with the correct column headers does indeed make perfect design sense in this case.  As I fought with the display problem, the database came online, allowing me to do the quick wire-up and as you correctly point out, no reason to leave it out.  Thanks again for your time on this question.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help - one last thought with regards to mock data; rather than contend with formatting the bound fields and the horrific potential to inadvertently lose the formatting on an accidental auto re-generation of the bound fields, you can simply return all text strings, formatted as you like, from the select.  That would make mock data a breeze, i.e. need more fields, expand the select and autoregen the gridview and voila, instant mock data